# The average of the field values when creating the object of the model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

How to calculate and add to field average of the field values ​​when creating the object of the model

example model:

```
class Metrics(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete='', default='', null=True)
    upload_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    agent_login = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    call_eq = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    zakaz_1 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    otkaz_1 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    zakaz_2 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    otkaz_2 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    zakaz_3 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    otkaz_3 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    zakaz_4 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    otkaz_4 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    zakaz_5 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

in "total" need to calculate average value.
How do it?

Comment: what field values, the `zazak_i`s and/or `otzak_i`s? I am not sure if this is a good modeling. Usually if you have a "mulitplicitly" of values, one usually creates a new model/table, with finer granularity.

Comment: total for each row in the db? if yes, you could calculate the total on every save, either overriding `save` on the model (preferred) or using signals.

Comment: @benzkji: personally I thin that overriding `.save()` and/or using signals, are not a good approach to such problems, since the Django ORM has ways to *circumvent* these. For example with `Metrics.objects.update(zazak_1=2)` I can update a field, and the `.save()` and signals will *not* be called.

Comment: What does "average value" mean here exactly ? And do you really need to store it in the database ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in English it means `order_1`, `reject/refusal_1` and so on.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem totally true. forgot to mention that point - you'll need to be aware of! A more elegant solution requires more work, like creating a view. Or, even a custom query via ORM, using SUM and the like - but this again would probably be too much processing involved on the SQL side. Having the total saved on the model has advantages, but also many disadvantages.

Comment: @benzkji storing a value computed from other values violates 5th normal form. One should only consider denormalization when there really are compelling reasons, since - as Willem mentions - it quickly leads to stale / inexact / eventually corrupted data. In this case, the cost of a sum - either at the database level (preferably) or at the client code level shouldn't be a concern for most use case and avoids a lot of troubles and potential errors, so unless you really have a critical performance issue it's better to stick to a properly normalized schema.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers completely agreed as well. just answered the OPs question ;-) SO often forces you to "should I just answer or should I teach, or both" side of things. also, the question needs clarification, that's why it was not posted as an answer.